# Roy model question

Tags: econometrics, causality

I am referring to G.S. Maddala: Limited Dependent and Qualitative Variables in Econometrics, pages 257-258. I add the relevant screenshots here:

[image: p1]
[image: p2]

My question is, why is $\sigma_{2u}>\sigma_{1u}$?

I am not seeing this?

I tried the following:
\begin{align}
 \sigma_{2u}>\sigma_{1u}\\
(\sigma^2_{2}-\sigma_{12})/\sigma>(\sigma_{12}-\sigma^2_{1})/\sigma\\
\sigma^2_{2}-\sigma_{12}>\sigma_{12}-\sigma^2_{1}\\
\sigma^2_{2}+\sigma^2_{1}>2\sigma_{12}
\end{align}
But why should $\sigma^2_{2}+\sigma^2_{1}>2\sigma_{12}$ be fulfilled? This is not necessarily the case?

Comment: If that inequality were not true, what would the correlation coefficient be?

Comment: @whuber correlation= cov/(std.dev1 * std.dev2). But I do not get your point?

Comment: Using that definition you can establish that the correlation would exceed $1$ if the inequality were not true.  But correlations cannot exceed $1$.